# data leak when generate key with winapi function

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cryptoapi, wincrypt

I have question: when I'm trying to generate AES key 128 lenght with `CryptGenKey` I have data leak?

Code below:

```
void GeKey(HCRYPTKEY hKey, HCRYPTPROV hProvs)
{
    DWORD len_iv = 0;

    if (!CryptGenKey(hProvs, CALG_AES_128, CRYPT_EXPORTABLE, &hKey))
    {
        ExitProcess(0);
    }

    if (!CryptExportKey(hKey, NULL, PLAINTEXTKEYBLOB, NULL, NULL, &len_iv))
    {
        ExitProcess(0);
    }

    unsigned char* aes_key_dec = new unsigned char[len_iv];

    if (!CryptExportKey(hKey, NULL, PLAINTEXTKEYBLOB, NULL, aes_key_dec, &len_iv))
    {
        ExitProcess(0);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < len_iv; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", aes_key_dec[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    delete[] aes_key_dec;
}
```

`delete[] aes_key_dec;` can't help me with this issue. What's wrong :/

Comment: You seem unsure if you have or do not have a data leak - please clarify.  _"... I have data leak?..."_ and _"...What's wrong..."_

Comment: @RichardCritten I mean, how to fix it?

Comment: Fix what?  What is unclear about the question is what you are asking us to fix.

Comment: Use std::unique_ptr to hold the pointer to aes_key_dec, and you'll know it would be deleted whichever way the routine exits.